# Executing shell commands in C#

Tags: c#, bash, shell

I am trying to execute shell commands [which is supposed to be in cygwin's sh.exe] through a c# program.

```
    Process proc = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe", "history");
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
```

But i'm getting the following error instead of getting the list of commands

```
   /usr/bin/sh: history: No such file or directory
```

Can you please let me know what i'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Why do You want execute Linux shell commands in Windows?

Comment: @karl-henrik Thanks it worked. But while i pass commands with "-c history" i'm not getting any previous list of commands. But the same does returns a list in sh shell.

Comment: @Kalai - A guess: you create a new instance of that shell, which shouldn't have a history yet of itself. Or should that history work over multiple shell instances?

Comment: I think @HansKesting is correct - you are starting the shell as a system process rather than the process that normally executes the shell and that might not have a history.